# Accessing function in Python dictionary

Tags: python

```
class Solution:
    def add(x) -> int:
        return x + 1

    def sub(x) -> int:
        return x - 1

    def finalValueAfterOperations(self, operations: List[str]) -> int:
        switch = {"X++": add, "++X": add, "X--": sub, "--X": sub}
        x = 0
        for i in range(len(operations)):
            x = switch[operations[i]](x)

        return x
```

Getting an error while doing this:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Solution' and 'int'
    x = switch[operations[i]](self,x)
Line 20 in finalValueAfterOperations (Solution.py)
    ret = Solution().finalValueAfterOperations(param_1)
```

I replaced the function with `"X++": lambda x : x+1` for all cases and it works.
How do i make it work for function ?

Comment: The code you have doesn't even run as-is. "name 'add' is not defined"

Comment: The erroring line, `x = switch[operations[i]](self,x)`, isn't in your code. For debugging help in the future, you'll need to make a [mre] including complete but minimal code, example input, expected output, and actual output--or if you get an error, the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341).

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible that you'd get the error you've pasted from the code you've pasted.

In any case, assuming you do wish to keep things encapsulated in a class (for whichever reason), the issue is that you'd need to either define the operations as free functions, like

```
from typing import List


def add(x) -> int:
    return x + 1


def sub(x) -> int:
    return x - 1


class Solution:

    def compute(self, operations: List[str], x=0) -> int:
        switch = {"X++": add, "++X": add, "X--": sub, "--X": sub}
        for op in operations:
            x = switch[op](x)

        return x


print(Solution().compute(["X++", "++X", "X--"]))
```

or as real methods and refer to them as such:

```
from typing import List


class Solution:

    def add(self, x) -> int:
        return x + 1

    def sub(self, x) -> int:
        return x - 1

    def compute(self, operations: List[str], x=0) -> int:
        switch = {"X++": self.add, "++X": self.add, "X--": self.sub, "--X": self.sub}
        for op in operations:
            x = switch[op](x)

        return x


print(Solution().compute(["X++", "++X", "X--"]))
```

or perhaps as `@staticmethod`s since you don't need `self`:

```
from typing import List


class Solution:

    @staticmethod
    def add(x) -> int:
        return x + 1

    @staticmethod
    def sub(x) -> int:
        return x - 1

    def compute(self, operations: List[str], x=0) -> int:
        switch = {"X++": self.add, "++X": self.add, "X--": self.sub, "--X": self.sub}
        for op in operations:
            x = switch[op](x)

        return x


print(Solution().compute(["X++", "++X", "X--"]))
```